# std::list in struct resulting in memory violation errors

Tags: c++, list, struct, std

I'm trying to use a list in a struct I have like this:

```
typedef struct _MS
{
    DWORD id;
    std::list<std::wstring> titles;
} MS;
```

But I'm having some problems when I try to use it.

When I look at it under the debugger at runtime 'titles = 0xcdcdcdcd', and when I try to call `_iterator = MS.titles.begin()` it fails with a memory access violation.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value `0xcdcdcdcd` is used by the MS compiler to mark memory that has been deleted.

Your problem is likely not with `std::list`, but with using  a pointer to a deleted object.

Comment: I've set a breakpoint right where my struct is allocated mystruct = (MS*)malloc(sizeof(MS)); and the list still has that value, what could be wrong?

Comment: A struct containg a `std::list` cannot (easily) be allocated using  `malloc`. You should use `new MS` so the list constructor is executed.

Comment: Ah, that was it :) Stupid old habits. Thanks a lot Bo!